# Generate JAXB episode file with Gradle anttask

Tags: ant, gradle, jaxb, build.gradle

I set up a gradle task to generate java classes from XSD files:

```
ant.taskdef(name: 'xjc', classname: 'com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask', classpath: configurations.jaxb.asPath)
ant.jaxbTargetDir = jaxbTargetDir
ant.xjc(destdir: '${jaxbTargetDir}', package: 'com.example') {
      schema(dir:'/home/bruckwald/proj/schema/xsd', includes: '*.xsd')
}
```

How can I pass the argument `-episode my.episode` to the ant task so that the episode file will be generated? 
I'm using the following dependencies:

```
jaxb(
    'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11',
    'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11',
    'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11',
    'javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.12',
    'org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons:jaxb2-basics-ant:0.9.4'
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example from a build of mine that passes other arguments to the XJC task:

```
ant.xjc(destdir: genDir, package: pkgName, extension: true) {
    classpath { pathelement(path: configurations.xjcrun.asPath) }
    schema(dir: "src/main/resources/schema", includes: schemaName)
    arg(value: "-Xxew")
    arg(value: "-Xfluent-api")
}
```

I would imagine your "-episode" arg would work just like that.

Note that the "arg" function takes a SINGLE argument.  If you to specify a command-line option that takes a value besides the presence of the option itself, then you'll need TWO arg calls, one for the option string, and one for the value itself, so it might be like this:

```
arg(value: "-episode")
arg(value: "my.episode")
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this doesn't work. If I pass -episode with a filename parameter I get `unrecognized parameter`, if without then `an operand is missing`. I edited my answer to shows the jaxb dependencies I use.

Comment: How about you show exactly what you tried?  Note that the value provided to "arg" is a SINGLE argument.

Comment: Ah, that was it! Passing first ´-episode´ then the filename in a different argument did the trick! If you edit your answer I'll accpet it

Comment: I added an example that fits your problem.